# При попытке спарсить выдает [ ]

Tags: python

Хочу научиться парсингу, но после написания части кода выдает пустой список...

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://igromagnit.net/two-players/'
HEADERS = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.85 '
                  'YaBrowser/21.11.4.730 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': '*/*'}

def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r

def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('a', class_='short-item')

    print(items)


def parse():
    html= get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        get_content(html.text)
    else:
        print('Error')


parse()
```

Comment: это означает что `find_all` ничего не нашёл.

Comment: Danis, если я меня class_='short-item' на любой другой, то так же будет выводиться пустой список

Comment: Динамический сайт. Все не так просто как кажется